# Adding module next to existing in Joomla

Tags: joomla, background, position, css-float, components

in my Joomla template is of course the component included:

```
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

That fills the whole width of the parent container at the moment (with margins). The parent container has a background that stretches from the top of the site to the bottom of the component. What I want to do is add a position after the component to place a module there, but I want it next to the component.

But once I make the component `float:left` and add a `width:80%` or something so the module on the new position will float next to the component. But, the background from the parent container changes when I add a width other than 100% to the component and stops before the component begins.

How can I have the component have a smaller width than 100% and `float:left` with another position next to it without changing the background of the parent container?

Edit: I like to add that I cannot use `overflow:hidden` on the parent container since another element will be clipped if I do. Adding a background to component and the other position won't work either since the original background is wider.

Edit2: I found a solution to my problem. For future reference if anyone is interested: the float clearing part on [this](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/) page described my problem and clearing the float by adding a `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` after the last floating element solved my problem. If anyone has a cleaner, better solution I love to see it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version of Joomla you're using, but if it's 3.x, then you can use the `clearfix` class that comes with Bootstrap. It's a cleaner and more efficient approach to adding a clear div at the end of the parent element. So simply add the following to your parent container:

```
class="clearfix"
```

If you're using Joomla 2.5 then you can add the following to your template css file:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: '\0020';
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
    zoom: 1;
}
```

and then add the class as mentioned above.

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm using joomla 3, yes. But removing the clear:both element and adding the class clearfix still results in the problem. Clear:both works but clearfix not.